# dynamic queries for oData endpoint in javascript

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze, jaydata, datajs

Ok, the title is a bit of a mouthful, but it states what I'm looking for. I have an oData endpoint, and I'm interested in seeing if there are any projects out there (preferably open source, maybe based on datajs?) that let me point to the end point, and it gives me a grid, paging, and my end users the ability to do dynamic queries (as in, adding new query parameters and refreshing the grid).

Figure it's worth a shot to see if anyone else has been down this road before I go down it myself.

Comment: Great question. I was expecting one of the commercial component venders would provide this with an ASP.NET MVC control but I have yet to see it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to see something like the silverlight oData explorer; but in html/javascript, and with a more user friendly expression builder.

Answer (score 3):

Breeze is another open source library that performs dynamic queries in JavaScript for OData and Web API and is in active development:
http://www.breezejs.com

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it's still an actual question, but give a shot to [JayData](http://jaydata.org). This is a crossplatform data library, that supports oData and language natural or programmatic querying. Also it has some example on how to use it with jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

There is an OData javascript library (among other OData libraries) available here for download: http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk

Its not an actual explorer, but there is alot of source js to work with Odata there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the datajs library only works on IE, if you are planning to implement a mobile device app, it wont work. I had this problem with a prototype for iOS+SAP app

Edit: This might have been the case in 2010. Currently (2013/Q1) it just works with all browsers.

Comment: if this is the case, the datajs library is close to useless. Do you have any references to what the problems are with datajs and webkit based renders?

Comment: I can tell, that datajs DOES work on all of our test devices (we have many, like 10 different model). Here you can see a kindle passing all tests, 450 of them is oData. http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=349640958428797&set=a.348879961838230.79730.315494325176794&type=1&theater